# JQuery click brings me to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not so familiar with jquery. I made a popover but when i clicked on the button that i set the popover it brings me on top of the page. I tried to prevent default event but it didn't worked for me. I don't know where i'm wrong at. Here is my code:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Its just a few lines so wanted to write it in html file. What can i do to make it stay when i clicked on that button?

Here is my whole popover code:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Telefon" data-content="Call us: (123) 123 1234" class="btn btn-default" role="button">example</a>
```

Comment: Can you post html of the `[data-toggle="popover"]` ?

Comment: I posted in in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Burak Sümer, Remove `#` from href and change it to:

`href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Thank you very much @BurakSümer for accepting my answer. Can you give me a vote for it ?
Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're preventing the default on the document.ready event, not on the click. You say that you're clicking on the button to get the popover, so you need to preventDefault() on the click event. If you post the popover() function (it's not a jQuery standard one AFAIK) we may be able to help you further.

Comment: I added the popover html. I'm using the bootstrap and jQuery for the .js files and also for the functions.

Comment: Ah - you didn't mention Bootstrap in the OP! Glad you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you do not prevent anything in your code.

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

gets called once the DOM is fully loaded. There is no event to prevent at that point.
What you want is to prevent the default behavior once you click the actual popover-element. You can achieve this like so:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return true;
});
```

Now your popup will display as expected and the scrolling should disappear.

You may as well remove the `href="#"` part that I *assume* is defined on your popover-element. Just do so if you do not need it!

Comment: If `href` is the culprit... Removing `href="#"` will fix the issue. `e.preventDefault();` is not necessary and bootstrap will take care rest.

Comment: When i remove href part popover is not working. So i may do something like href="#idontexist" but then url looks bad. I want it to be like this.

Comment: It made whole thing not work. Maybe its about my code, i don' know.